# careers.so profiles should also allow non-open-source projects as "projects"

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs

#### Current state

Currently the carreers.stackoverflow profiles only allow open-source projects to be mentioned in your "projects" section.

#### Problem I see

This does not represent a professional developer's portfolio. Most developers spend a major part of their time working on commercial projects. Running a popular website or having created (and selling) a useful product/service is - in my understanding - much more representive than a free-time open-source project. Also keep in mind that some of us have created software that is used by thousands or millions, but still not open-source.

#### Possible To-Do

Open this section for simple listing of websites, companies, products, etc. the user has created or was part in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily you can already do this! Under the Apps & Software section you can add a link to any website or software that you've created or been part of.

1. Click add an application...
2. Enter the URL of the project/software/website.
3. Enter the Name, description, technologies, and your role/contribution.

Comment: Okay, I see! The "completeness"-overview links directly to the open source section, so I have obviously totally overseen this! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your feedback! We actually have a separate section for this, "Apps & Software". Projects such as app store apps or commercial software can be included there.